# What is the meaning of なす? Specifically when preceded by a color

Tags: grammar, usage

I came across this phrase in a book:

> 緑なす半島

Obviously (and also confirmed by [Weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B7%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%99)) it is describing a quality of the peninsula, but I'm curious as to what exactly it means, and how/when it can be used.

I found a [forum discussion](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6094) on its use as compared to `なる`, but it doesn't seem to me to be used in the same way as where I found it. (It generally concluded that is was a transitive version of `なる`...which I can't say is wrong, but I don't think I really understood what they were trying to say, and I think it requires a particle {`を`?} in order to be used like that.)

Comment: As a sidenote: this usage seems more suited for poetry than everyday conversation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, なす appears to translate to something like "made" or "like" (as in, "made-green" or "like-green" in regards to the growth of foliage.)  緑なす can also relate to one having glossy, dark hair.

But I would suggest that なす preceded with a color does not always equate to this type of usage.  緑 seems to be special as it relates to natural colors or foliage (see second definition on [this dictionary entry](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B7%91).)

In regard to the actual use of なす here, it may historically be a remnant from poetic usage.  See [this possible explanation](http://cgi21.plala.or.jp/mizuhote/oshietebbs/oshiete.cgi?pastlog=0002&no=636&act=past&mode=allread) (No.640) for more information (though this is only, evidently, speculation.)

Although it's not preceded by a color, this possible explanation cites a use of なす in a particular poetic verse by [加藤楸邨{かとうしゅうそん}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A0%E8%97%A4%E6%A5%B8%E9%82%A8) ([reference](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%81%AF%E3%82%92%E6%B6%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%84%E3%81%93%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E5%B4%96%E3%81%AA%E3%81%99%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AE%E5%89%8D)):

> 灯を消すやこころ崖なす月の前

Answer (score 6):

nasu is a suffix that is attached to nouns and means "like" or "similar to". Some of these phrases are more common than others such as 山なす大波 "a mountain-like large wave".

But in this case, "midori nasu" is a common phrase meaning for trees and plants to grow in abundance. So it is a peninsula rich in plant life.